# Assign a variable name to an array object in D3.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, geojson, topojson

The code as it stands currently works fine, the only addition is I would like to assign a name to the object that is sent to the console using the `clicky` function. The console returns `Object {type: "MultiPolygon", coordinates: Array[1]}` and I would like to assign that to a variable name so it can be referenced later when I bring in a CSV file with the same generated name. How do I go about doing that?

```
var northcentral = {
  "47": 1, "37": 1, "45": 1, "13": 1
};

var northcentral_c = {
  "25": 1, "09": 1, "44": 1, "50": 1, "33": 1, "23" :1
};  

var svg = d3.select("svg");

var path = d3.geoPath();

var nc = [];
Array.prototype.push.apply(nc,us.objects.states.geometries.filter(function(d) { return d.id in northcentral; }))
Array.prototype.push.apply(nc,us.objects.counties.geometries.filter(function(d) { return d.id in northcentral_c; }))

svg.append("path")
  .datum(topojson.merge(us, nc))
  .attr("class", "state northcentral")
  .attr("d", path)
  .on("click", clicky);

function clicky(d){
  console.log(d);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there's this:

```
var dWhichWasClicked = null

function clicky(d){
  console.log(d);
  dWhichWasClicked = d
}
```

By declaring `dWhichWasClicked` outside of `clicky()`, it is available (i.e. in scope) to any other code in that file, whereas if `dWhichWasClicked` were declared inside `clicky()` it would only be in scope within that function.

That being said, it's generally a bad idea to use global variables, and while this approach is not necessarily a global variable, it comes close.

You could simply have a function that loads the csv:

```
function loadCSV(filename) {
  // load it now
}
```

And call it from the click handler

```
function clicky(d){
  console.log(d);
  loadCSV( getFilenameFor(d) )
}
```